# Javascript date calculation result "NaN"

Tags: javascript

There are two inputs and one output.
input 1: Start Date (string type)
input 2: End Date (string type)
output: End Date - Start Date

In input 1 the user selects the start date and in input 2, the user selects the end date.
The end date is optional. So, I want that if the user doesn't select an End date, input 2 should be the Current date.

I tried different things but didn't work.

```
const startInput = document.querySelector(".exp_start").innerHTML;
const endInput = document.querySelector(".exp_end").innerHTML;
var end = function endCalc() {
    if (endInput == null) {
    new Date();
}
    else {
    endOutput;
}
}; 
const startDate = new Date(startInput);
const endDate = new Date(end);
const time = Math.abs(endDate - startDate);
const years = Math.abs(time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30.5) / 12).toFixed(1);
document.querySelector(".exp_years").innerHTML = years;
```

I expected the result to be the number of years (like "2"). But the result I got was "NaN".
I don't know what's wrong with the code...

[The result is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7svOQ.png)

Comment: `new Date();` - you are not doing anything with the result of this. Your function should _return_ a value, you want it to be assigned to `end` after all. (And `endOutput` does not appear to exist either.)

Comment: And `innerHTML` is not the correct way to get the value of an input field either, that's `value`.

Comment: `new Date(end)` makes no sense. `end` is a function, and even if you had called it (`end()`) it wouldn't have returned a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const startInput = document.querySelector(".exp_start").value;
const endInput = document.querySelector(".exp_end").value;
const startDate = new Date(startInput);
const endDate = endInput?new Date(endInput):new Date();
const time = Math.abs(endDate - startDate);
const years = Math.abs(time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30.5) / 12).toFixed(1);
document.querySelector(".exp_years").innerHTML = years;
```